# javascript file is returning an error log that Im not sure about

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

One of my javascript files is returning an error log on the following line

```
if(strinput.indexOf('<?')>-1||strinput.indexOf('!xml')>-1||strinput.indexOf('xml')>-1)
```

and the error is

```
[20-Apr-2012 14:06:32] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '!'
in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/phpspellcheck/include.js on line 295
```

but if I remove the ! the error changes to

```
[20-Apr-2012 14:15:40] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 
/home6/mywebsite/public_html/phpspellcheck/include.js on line 295
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this error showing up? Why would JS be getting parsed by PHP?

Comment: This isn't a jQuery error, it is a php error.

Comment: This error is in my websites error log.  A third party that I hired to help me out wrote a PHP script that parses this JS file as part of a spellcheck function

Comment: It's not a "jQuery" file, it's a JavaScript file. jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: @Rookieatthis, if you don't know *why* the file is interpreted as PHP, it could be a good idea to ask that at http://serverfault.com/ instead, since the question better relates to server administration than to programming.

Comment: This is all very helpful.  I am just learning and you guys are great teachers.  I am new to all of this and your input is showing me a lot.  Sorry for what seems like a stupid question, but I am completely sincere and want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the server is interpreting the files as PHP (and that is invalid PHP syntax) instead of sending them as they are to the client to be interpreted as JavaScript.